# How to remove missing pages from Solr when old Nutch crawldb is missing?

Tags: solr, nutch

Suppose I ran Apache Nutch to crawl a website, and it added documents to an Apache Solr core. Suppose I now delete the Apache Nutch directory containing the crawldb. If some of the pages on the website have been removed in the meantime, and I now run a new crawl (with a new crawldb), the missing pages will still be indexed by Solr.

Normally, with the old crawldb present, Nutch will attempt to fetch all the pages it knows about from its previous crawls, and for pages that give 404, it will instruct Solr to delete them from its index. In my case, however, I've deleted the old crawldb, so Nutch will start crawling from scratch, and it will not know about the pages previously available that now give 404.

What is an appropriate way to make Nutch remove entries in Solr if the old Nutch crawldb has been deleted (accidentally or otherwise)? In other words, how to delete documents in Solr that are not also in the Nutch crawldb?

Is starting a new Solr core and deleting the old Solr core the only available option?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, the newly created crawldb just triggers an index *update*, because Nutch has no more way to instruct Solr to handle a delete query with specific IDs (no info about deleted docs).

Re-indexing usually implies a deletion not of the *core* but of the *index* (unless you track each document status eg. `deleted:<0|1>`, in which case it would be possible to retrieve|exclude deleted documents) :

```
/solr/<core>/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

But there might be another way, using a small script :

- Query Solr to retrieve all documents (including the one to be deleted). Use `fl` parameter to grab the url of each doc.
- In a loop : based on each document url, manually fetch the webpage the document points to.
- Depending on the response status code of each request (if not ok..), mark the corresponding document to be deleted.
- With the collected docId, prepare a delete-by-query statement using `OR` operator :

  ```
  <delete><query>id:(123 OR 456 OR 789) </query></delete>
  ```

Comment: Idea: query Solr to retrieve all URLs, and also get all URLs in the Nutch crawldb. Then, delete from Solr the URLs that are present in Solr but not present in the Nutch crawldb. Is this feasible? I am new to Solr.

Comment: Yes, in this case the 1st and last step should stay the same in your script, it doesn't change anything from Solr' perspective. Instead of trying to fetch web pages from the (old) collected urls, you build an <id:url> map from the *new* crawldb, and then compare this collection with what has been left in the index, docIds only present in the index should be deleted.